# Print specific value from JSON object with JS

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am new to JSON. I have a JSON String. I want to access the data and print it to a DIV which i get working like this:

```
document.getElementById("product_content").innerHTML=javascript_array[5].name;
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
$data[] = array(
  "id"    =>  $product->virtuemart_product_id,
  "name"  =>  $product->product_name
);
```

which has already been encoded and works.

How would i get a specific value using a id to retrieve the name eg:

```
document.getElementById("product_content").innerHTML=javascript_array["id" == 3].name;
```

instead of using the row number i say where "id" == 3 like **"id" == 3**

Thanks for the help

Comment: You can't. You have to loop through your array and do something like `if(current_item.id == 3) ...`.

Comment: There's no such thing as "json objects". There's json **STRINGS**, which you can decode into a native data structure, e.g. a javascript object or array. You don't manipulate or deal with JSON directly. Consider it the box that some data ships inside. You don't use the box for anything EXCEPT shipping. You have to unpackage the data first, and then use it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can rework the PHP to this you'll be in a better position

```
$data[$product->virtuemart_product_id] = array(
  "name"  =>  $product->product_name
);
```

This will set the ID as the key, rather than as additional element of the contained array. You should then be able to do

```
javascript_array[5]
```

If you are expecting strings too you should do

```
javascript_array["a_string"]
```

Or

```
javascript_array.a_string
```

Comment: Thanks, but the id's are not incrementing values, they differ...would it be possible to `javascript_array[13]` where 13 is the id of the product. Sorry i am very new to JSON

Comment: The id could be anything, string or number.